# I have these 5 panels in my tabbed pane..I want that when the input in my combo box i 2 ..all panels except panel 8 should b disabled

Tags: java, swing

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    int n= Integer.parseInt(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    System.out.println(""+n);
    if(n==2)
    {
     jPanel8.setVisible(true);
     jPanel9.setVisible(false);
     jPanel10.setVisible(false);
     jPanel11.setVisible(false);
     jPanel2.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) So what's the problem?

Comment: its not disabling the tabs.

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its not disabling the tabs

Why do you think making a panel invisible will disable a tab?

If you want to disable a tab then take a look at the `JTabbedPane` API.

Look at all the "setter" methods. You will find a method that allows you to disable individual tabs.